# How to use the "how" function for an unbalanced repeated design

Tags: r, permutation, vegan

I have a set of control and treated plots which had been sampled during years. I run the *prc* function in the *vegan* package and want to perform a permutation test to check whether control vs treated plots significantly differ during years. As my data is unbalanced, I can not use *strata* function. my code look like:

```
library(vegan)
year=as.factor(c(rep(1995,8),rep(1999,8),rep(2001,8),rep(2013,4),rep(1995,4),
       rep(1999,4),rep(2001,4),rep(2013,4)))
treatment=as.factor(c(rep("control",28),rep("treated",16)))
```

I've written this, but I'm sure that it is wrong because the treatment is missing here:

```
h1 <- how(within = Within(type = "series", mirror = F),
          blocks = year, nperm = 999
)
```

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So why exactly are you sure it's wrong? What exactly is your question here? What is the desired outcome? What hypothesis are you trying to test?

Comment: @MrFlick the code misses the treatment. I want to test wether the species composition of treated plots signficantly differ from controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the null hypothesis, samples from the `control` or `treated` groups *are* exchangeable and hence you don't want them in the permutation design; you really want to permute them to generate the permutation-based null distribution for the test statistic.

The permutation design is there to indicate what *isn't* exchangeable.

You haven't explained why you want samples *within* the blocks to be permuted in series; why are samples within years also time series? If they're not, you don't want this.

You only need to worry about imbalance if you want to permute the `strata`. Whilst using `blocks` is similar in some respects to `strata`, `blocks` are *never* permuted so if you can use `blocks` you can use `strata` as you won't be permuting them.

If you want to permute the `years` as groups of samples, then you'll need `strata` and you'll need balance at the `year` level, which you don't have.

What you have defined with your call to `how()` is:

- groups samples by `year` and as such samples will *never* be swapped *between* years, and
- samples within the levels of `year` will be permuted in series, keeping their temporal order intact after applying cyclic shift permutations.

If that's not what you want to do, you need to explain in words what you want to do. By "do" I mean what is it you want to test? What is your model in *vegan*?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to evaluate the statistical significances of the
differences between treated and control plots. I am not sure if it is correct to have years as blocks for PRC analysis. Through literature, they have balanced design; I assume that they use strata, similar to what is described in the Vegan's PRC description.

Comment: std.sp=decostand(heath_sp,method = "hellinger")
mod <- prc(std.sp, Treatment, year)